# Loop is not changing directories , but I can print out the directory - why is that happening

Tags: python-3.x, output

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rawsource):
    print("root is {}".format(root))
    try:
        os.system("cd {}".format(root))
        print("root in the try: was {}".format(root))
        print("pwd is {}".format(os.system("pwd")))
```

I am not sure why: `os.system("cd {}".format(root))` is failing. Meaning, it doesnt appear to properly be changing directory `cd` to the value of `root`, but instead appears to be staying at `/Users/user/Project`

But, `print("root in the try: was {}".format(root))` is properly outputting the proper directory within the loop.

This is the output:

```
pwd is 0
root is /Users/user/Project/src/main/gateway
root in the try: was /Users/user/Project/src/main/gateway
/Users/user/Project
```

Why might this be happening?

Comment: What do you mean by failing?

Comment: See updated @Oso . Its printing only sub part of the path - see last line of output

Comment: The output does not appear to correspond with the version of the program in the question.

Comment: For each `system` call you get a new shell. So the first `os.system("cd {}".format(root))` changes to the new directory (likely) but the second `"pwd is {}".format(os.system("pwd"))` is in a new shell that knows nothing about the first shell.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `os.chdir` and `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: The `0` you are seeing is simply the successful return code. So `os.system("cd {}".format(root))` does this 1) spawns a shell; 2) executes the shell function `cd` with the argument supplied 3) givens the return code of `0` meaning it was done successfully and 4) EXITS!

Comment: @dawg - chdir and getcwd were exactly what i was missing. Its been a bit of time. Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason you want to change to a new directory? If you just want to print out file names or otherwise process the files in your python code, you should just do it directly without `os.system()`.

Comment: @dawg I think your first comment is the actual answer here because it describes why the OP sees the behavior they are asking about. The dupe links might be answers to the Y of this XY problem.